# Plane wave generation

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I've read that plane waves are idealizations, but I'm trying to get a mechanical intuition for plane waves.  In a classical E&M model, would cycled charging/discharging of a parallel plate capacitor with very large area generate a plane wave, or at least something very close to a plane wave, in regions between the plates near the surface?

I know that cycled charging/discharging of capacitors emit radiation.  I know that plane waves are a frequently-used model of wave propagation in optics. I can't recall reading about a connection between the two, and when I think backwards about how a plane wave would be generated, I imagine this a charging/discharging capacitor, but I don't know if I'm correct.

The only other way I imagine a plane wave being generated is mechanical vibration of a single charged plate.  Would this also generate a plane wave in classical E&M theory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EM plane waves have electric and magnetic vectors perpendicular. And both are perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

An alternating current in a capacitor produces an electric field between the plates, perpendicular to them, and a magnetic field normal to the $E$ field, circling around. The direction of a plane wave should be perpendicular to both, so it is not perpendicular to the plates of the capacitor.

The initial form of the waves near the source is not plane. But it is not so important, because a few hundred meters away, the spread circles are so big that from the point of view of a receptor, it is a plane wave for all practical purposes.